# Handling multiple ajax calls in react

Tags: ajax, reactjs, axios

The scenario I'm after is as following.

There are two different ajax calls which retrieve data from the server side in my react application. They don't need to be chained and the responses are not inter-depended. My current code is as following.

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.all([
        getOrganizationsForUser(this.state.accessToken, this.state.userId),
        getAllUsersOfOrganizationsTemp()
    ]).then(axios.spread((organizations, users) => {
        this.setState({
            userOrganizations: organizations.data,
            OrganizationUsers: users
        });
    }))
}
```

So when one call is rejected or failed, then the entire ajax call is failed in the above code. what is the best way to handle multiple, non related/ non depended ajax calls in react?

Comment: why not just make two calls? i don't see the advantage to grouping them if they are unrelated. I would argue grouping unrelated calls makes it less flexible and harder to read and its worth the extra code

Comment: is it the more professional way to handle multiple calls?

Comment: There isn't always a more professional way, its whatever the feature calls for and the decision of the programmer. In your case, I would say yes.

Answer (score 0):

why you want group your request call , if both of the request is separate from each other and not depended together ??

you can call multi axios call , and this way not reduce your performance

if you want set your one instance axios method , just for this reason , that you have some config on method and you dont want rewrite them you can make an instance of axios with create() method and then set your any configuration you want

see this

```
const instance = axios.create();
```

in above , you create an instance of axios , and then set your config in this way , for example you want set timeout

```
instance.defaults.timeout = 2500;
```

and after that you can get any request

```
 instance.get('/query', {
     // --------
  });
```

and if you want overwrite configuration , you can set in your  instance

```
 instance.get('/query', {
  timeout: 5000
   });
```